# Frozen-Flask, url_for() in Jinja2 and string concatenation during build

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-frozen

When running Flask normally, everything described below works absolutely fine.
When running a build in Frozen-Flask however, I run into the following issue:

In my Jinja2 template I tried this at first, where I'm having to create the route strings of many `url_for()` functions from multiple sources:

```py
{% macro my_macro(foo) %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('index_' ~ foo) }}">Link text</a>
{% endmacro %}
```

Although this runs fine in Flask, when I do a build with Frozen-Flask I get the following error:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index_'. Did you mean...
```

As you can see, the value of `foo` is missing.

So I thought that's annoying, but maybe the string concatenation of `'index_' ~ foo` happens after the `url_for()` is parsed. So to test my theory, I tried this instead:

```py
{% macro my_macro(foo) %}
    {% set route = 'index_' ~ foo %}
    <a href="{{ url_for(route) }}">Link text</a>
{% endmacro %}
```

But I get the exact same error. Exactly. So, as if it's setting the value of `set route` before concatenating the value of the `foo` variable onto the end of `'index_'`, and passing that incomplete value through to `url_for()`.

However, if I substitute `foo` for `'foo'` (so now foo is a string not a variable) then the concatenation works fine. So I can't concatenate string with string variables in Frozen-Flask?

Is there any way around this or is this maybe a possible bug in Frozen-Flask?

---

Update: It appears to be an issue with data coming from `routes.py` where I have `return render_template('my_template.html', foo='bar')`. This `foo` variable, although it is being passed through to the base template where in turn it is passed through to the macro (it can be output to prove the data present and correct) this data however cannot, it seems, be used to dynamically create a route for use by url_for().

Answer (score 0):

i think will help you a simple line code

```
      <a href="{{url_for('user')}}/{{foo}}">Link Text</a>
```

considering foo as string only will be concatenate, no with string1+strin2, only using html printing.

Comment: That can work, but it breaks away from the whole purpose of using `url_for()` and the `@route()` decorator.